# Hyperlink not opening with ShellExecute failed (error 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have an application developed using PYQT5, in this application I have a row in a QtableWidget with a QLabel hyperlink to a report.  The report is saved locally, though in future this may be located in a network share.

For the sake of this question, say I have a report on my local drive at this location:

```
C:\my\report\location\report.html
```

However when I click the link to open the report in a web browser I get an error in the console window saying:

```
ShellExecute 'c:%5Cmy%5Creport%5Clocation%5Creport.html' failed (error 2).
```

Obviously the script has issues with the '\' backslash property, but I am unable to find a way to prevent this.

Here's my pyqt based code to generate the hyperlink in the QTableWidget:

```
reportLink = " <a href=\"{url}\"> <font face=Tw Cen MT Condensed size=2 color=black>Report</font> </a>"\
    .format(url=outcome_dict['report_location'])
report_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel()
report_lbl.setText(reportLink)
report_lbl.setOpenExternalLinks(True)

self.ui.my_table.setCellWidget(self.row, 6, report_lbl)
```

And here's my code snippet when the user clicks the report hyperlink in the QTableWidget:

```
def html_clicked(self, mi):
    self.column = mi.column()
    if self.column == 6:
        try:
            for ref in self.ui.my_table.selectedIndexes():
                self.link = self.ui.my_table.item(int(ref.row()), 6).text()
            webbrowser.open(self.link)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)                
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to use webbrowser.open (...), the QLabel will indicate that there will be that link but for this it is necessary that the url is correct, in the case of a local file the url is `file:///path/of/file`, then to obtain that url using the path must use `QUrl::fromLocalFile()`, example:

```
class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = ...
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        d = [{"report_location": r"C:\my\report\location\report.html" },
             {"report_location": r"C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\index.html" }]

        self.ui.my_table.setColumnCount(7)
        self.ui.my_table.setRowCount(2)

        for row, outcome_dict in enumerate(d):
            url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(outcome_dict['report_location']).toString()
            reportLink = "<a href=\"{url}\"> <font face=Tw Cen MT Condensed size=2 color=black>Report</font> </a>"\
                        .format(url=url)
            report_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel()
            report_lbl.setText(reportLink)
            report_lbl.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
            self.ui.my_table.setCellWidget(row, 6, report_lbl)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```